# Does F# has a function to tell if a list contains a specific value?

Tags: f#, contain

Haskell has "elem" predicate to tell like:

```
Prelude> 5 `elem` [2,4..10]
False
```

In F#, how to conveniently tell whether a value is in a list, or array, or seq or map, or dictionary?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use:

```
List.exists ((=) 5) [1..5]
```

Or as suggested in the other answer, directly `List.contains` if you have the latest F# version.

The same functions are available for `Seq`.

Comment: Also available for `Array`. It is also worth mentioning that if you are on an older version of F# than 4.0, you can instead use the Linq extension methods: e.g. `[1..5].Contains(5)`

Answer (score 15):

In F# it is

```
List.contains <element> <list>
```

Example:

```
List.contains 5 [2..2..10]
```

-->

```
val it : bool = false
```

`contains` is also defined for the other container types.